# business catalyst liquid markup for blog tags

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

I am using the blogposts resource to output my blogposts and added pagination to render three posts at a time. This is working as it is suppose to. But with the blogposts resource I have also added `fields="tag" subresource="tags` So I can render the tags associated with each blogpost.

But I am not being able to output this part. This is code I have used:

```
{% if globals.get.limit %}
    {% assign limit = globals.get.limit | convert: "number" %}
{% else %}
    {% assign limit = 3 %}
{% endif %}

{% if globals.get.skip %}
    {% assign skip = globals.get.skip | convert: "number" %}
{% else %}
    {% assign skip = 0 %}
{% endif %}

{% assign resource = "blogposts" fields="tag" subresource="tags"%}

{module_data resource="{{resource}}" version="v3" template="" limit="{{limit}}" skip="{{skip}}" collection="bpost"}

{% assign moduloCheck =  bpost.totalItemsCount | modulo :limit %}

{% if moduloCheck == 0 %}
    {% assign totalPages = bpost.totalItemsCount | divided_by: limit | minus: 1 %}
{% else %}
    {% assign totalPages = bpost.totalItemsCount | divided_by: limit %}
{% endif %}

{% assign currentPage =  globals.get.skip|divided_by:limit %}
<hr />
{% for item in bpost.items %}
    <h2>{{item.postTitle}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.postBody}}</p>
    <p>Skapad&nbsp;<span>{{item.releaseDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd \ hh:mm:ss tt"}}</span></p>
    <p><a href="{{item.postUrl}}">Kommentera</a></p>
    <br />
    <ul>
        {% for item in bpost.items -%}
            <li><a href="/retreivepostsbytag.html?tagid={{item.tag.id}}"># {{item.tag.tagName}}</a></li>
        {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
    <hr />
{% endfor %}

<span>Sida:
    {% for pageNum in (0..totalPages) %}
        {% if pageNum == currentPage %}
            {{ pageNum | plus: 1 }}
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ globals.get.id }}?skip={{ pageNum|times:globals.get.limit }}&amp;limit={{ limit }}">{{ pageNum | plus: 1 }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</span>
```

Heres a test page I am trying to implement this code upon: [testpage](http://gladahundarx.businesscatalyst.com/blog_post_pagination)

Thanks,
-Sohail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subresource request for the tag data needs to happen once for each post, like so:

```
{% for item in bpost.items %}
    ...

    {module_data resource="blogposts" version="v3" fields="objectId,tagId,objectType,siteId,tag,post" subresource="tags" resourceId="{{ item.id }}" skip="0" limit="10" order="objectType" collection="postTagData"}
    <ul>
        {% for tagMeta in postTagData.items -%}
            <li>
                <a href="/retreivepostsbytag.html?tagid={{ tagMeta.tag.id }}"
                  >{{ tagMeta.tag.tagName }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor -%}
    </ul>

    ...
{% endfor %}
```

---

Also, your `resource` variable was only ever being set to `blogposts`, the other part (`fields="tag" subresource="tags"`) was getting discarded. I'd change it to this, for clarity:

```
{% assign resource = "blogposts" %}
```

---

EDIT: Here's your code, modified to include the changes:

```
{% if globals.get.limit %}
    {% assign limit = globals.get.limit | convert: "number" %}
{% else %}
    {% assign limit = 3 %}
{% endif %}

{% if globals.get.skip %}
    {% assign skip = globals.get.skip | convert: "number" %}
{% else %}
    {% assign skip = 0 %}
{% endif %}

{% assign resource = "blogposts" %} <!-- `fields="tag" subresource="tags"` was being discarded -->

{module_data resource="{{resource}}" version="v3" template="" limit="{{limit}}" skip="{{skip}}" collection="bpost"}

{% assign moduloCheck =  bpost.totalItemsCount | modulo :limit %}

{% if moduloCheck == 0 %}
    {% assign totalPages = bpost.totalItemsCount | divided_by: limit | minus: 1 %}
{% else %}
    {% assign totalPages = bpost.totalItemsCount | divided_by: limit %}
{% endif %}

{% assign currentPage =  globals.get.skip|divided_by:limit %}
<hr />

{% for item in bpost.items %}
    <h2>{{item.postTitle}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.postBody}}</p>
    <p>Skapad&nbsp;<span>{{item.releaseDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd \ hh:mm:ss tt"}}</span></p>
    <p><a href="{{item.postUrl}}">Kommentera</a></p>
    <br />

    {module_data resource="blogposts" version="v3" fields="objectId,tagId,objectType,siteId,tag,post" subresource="tags" resourceId="{{ item.id }}" skip="0" limit="10" order="objectType" collection="postTagData"}
    <ul>
        {% for tagMeta in postTagData.items -%}
            <li>
                <a href="/retreivepostsbytag.html?tagid={{ tagMeta.tag.id }}"
                    >{{ tagMeta.tag.tagName }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor -%}
    </ul>

    <hr />
{% endfor %}

<span>Sida:
    {% for pageNum in (0..totalPages) %}
        {% if pageNum == currentPage %}
            {{ pageNum | plus: 1 }}
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ globals.get.id }}?skip={{ pageNum|times:globals.get.limit }}&amp;limit={{ limit }}">{{ pageNum | plus: 1 }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wondering one thing though. The ul tag items is repeated three times for each blog post. Is this due to limit for the the collection bpost is set to 3? 
If so, is there a way to remedy this so the tags list only loops once for each blogpost?

Comment: @user2371684 you need only loop over `bpost.items` once, so you'll end up with exactly as many `<ul>`s as `<h2>`.

Comment: So what portion of the code do I need to change to accomplish this as the limit set to the collection bpost is set to 3 to enable only three posts per page?
Or am I completely wrong about where it loops three times?

Comment: @user2371684 I've update the answer to show the changes in context.